# Selenium MicrosoftEdgeDriver will not resize browser accurately

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, galen, selenium-edgedriver, microsoft-webdriver

I am running some visual regression tests under the Galen framework, using MicrosoftEdgeDriver.  Is anyone else having an issue where the browser being resized to a number different than desired?

When sizing to, say, height = 640 and width = 360, I get the following:

`System.out.println("edge browser size: " + getDriver().manage().window().getSize());
System.out.println("expected browser size is: " + height + ", " + width);`

result:

`edge browser size: (768, 383)
expected browser size is: 640, 360`

for height x width of 1024x768:

`edge browser size: (768, 383)
expected browser size is: 640, 360`

for height x width = 768x1024:

`edge browser size: (777, 1028)
expected browser size is: 768, 1024`

Since this behavior is consistent, my tests are passing, but I just want to ensure that I am not missing something, or if there is indeed an issue with MicrosoftWebDriver.exe.

I have not conducted the same test in firefox, chrome, or IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as expected, as window size is the size of the outer windows, see [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#getSize--): "... This will return the outer window dimension, not just the view port."

Galen sets the view port size as this is the one affecting the rendering!

Comment: from the link:
"Dimension getSize()
Get the size of the current window. This will return the outer window dimension, not just the view port.
Returns:
The current window size."

Of course!